# “Unable to find a matching set of capabilities” with Selenium and Python and current Firefox on Windows 10

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have the following installed:

- Window 10 (version 1709)
- Firefox v59 (64-bit)
- Python 3.6.5
- Selenium 3.11.0 for Python
- GeckoDriver 0.20.0

There is a sample test called "Example 0" from the official Selenium Python site: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium. This is the entire test:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

When I run it, it complains "`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`"

Searching Stack Overflow for a solution, I find [other suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345916/914778), like this test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, firefox_binary=binary)
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

Running that, I get the following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4t_plvms If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

I have Firefox v59, so the error says I should use GeckoDriver. Problem is, the first test above ("Example 0") used the GeckoDriver, and that had the "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" error. The proposed solution to that error is to set "`cap["marionette"] = False`" in the second test, but that approach fails.
I just can't win. How can I resolve this? I'd like to successfully run the "Example 0" test from the official Selenium Python site.

(P.S. this is not a duplicate question. All other similar questions have Firefox v54 or earlier, and are able to use the "marionette = False" approach. I'm using Firefox 59 and can't use that approach.)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I had Firefox 64-bit, Python 3.6 32-bit, and GeckoDriver 32-bit.

1. I uninstalled Python 32-bit, then installed [Python 64-bit](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-amd64-webinstall.exe).
2. Downloaded GeckoDriver 64-bit and corrected the 'path' in Environment Variables to point to the 64-bit driver.
3. Restart the computer.
4. I also ran 'pip uninstall selenium' then 'pip install selenium', although that probably wasn't necessary.